# Arranging number is order - SQL Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in development but I have a basic background

I have two columns `(ID (numeric)`, `Created_ON (date with timestamp))` and they already filled.

I want the number is ID to be arranged like this: `ID = 1` (given to the raw that had the oldest (Created_On) Date and so on

I want it to be arranged like this:

```
ID -------- Created_On

1 --------- (The oldest date)
```

And to continue for the next raws from the oldest date to the newest date.

What's a suitable query for it?

Comment: Hi @MuntherYousef, please can you try to explain little bit better ? "I want the number is ID to be arranged like this: ID = 1 (given to the raw that had the oldest (Created_On) Date and so on" this is the part I do not understand. Maybe you can give us some small data example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, changing the `id` column is not recommended.  After all, it might be used for foreign key relationships.  Or someone might be storing some values in a spreadsheet somewhere.

That said, you are asking how to do it.  Here is one method:

```
update t
    set t.id = tt.new_id
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by created_on) as new_id
          from t
         ) tt
    where t.id = tt.id and t.id <> tt.new_id;
```

If you have a unique constraint on `id`, then it is possible to have issues when running code like this.  For the update, you can drop or disable the constraint and then add it back or enable it afterwards.